# What's a verb for discerning boundaries of the constituents of a seemingly amorphous whole?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a verb for discerning the boundaries of distinct entities that are constituents of a seemingly amorphous whole? "Gaining resolution" is the closest phrase I can think of, but that's a metaphor where I want to be explicit.

> Example of sentence structure in use case:
>
> 1. *Zooming in on the image ____ its contents.*
> 2. *The professor **demystified (???)** Newtonian physics.*
> 3. *Putting on his glasses will **discriminate (???)** Bob's vision of the forest.*

I want to express the idea that a seemingly amorphous entity has had its contents revealed sophisticated and articulate.

---

The two verbs I know of that could be potential candidates, "discern" and "discriminate", feel awkward. They're usually used in the structure of "discriminate between X and Y" or "discern between X and Y".

To say that "putting on glasses discriminated his vision" feels wrong, and I'm not sure anyone will even understand me if I use that strange wording.

Could there be a better word? Or should I stick with "discriminate"?

Comment: It's probably a duplicate, but you can think about 'define'.

Comment: I don't see why you shy away from 'resolve' (in the sense of 'bring into focus'). It isn't a metaphor in the context of perceiving something, even if the something is abstract rather than concrete.

Answer (score 1):

[**Clarify**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clarify):

> transitive verb
>
> 1 : to make understandable · clarify a subject · The president was forced to *clarify* his position on the issue.
>
> 2 : to free of confusion · needs time to *clarify* his thoughts
>
> intransitive verb
>
> to become clear · waiting for the present muddled diplomatic situation to *clarify*

For your sentences:

> 1. Zooming in on the image clarifies its contents.
> 2. The professor clarified Newtonian physics.
> 3. Putting on his glasses will clarify Bob's vision of the forest.